# Can I freeze the header row of a fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've got data from 50 states that I'd like to display in the table format (I've also got it mapped) but the table height is so large that you can't scroll down without losing the header row. Since there's 13 columns with yes/no information, once you lose sight of that row it becomes difficult to understand what you're reading.

I would love to be able to freeze the header row so that data below it can scroll (in both x and y axes). I thought about using an image on top of the table but that doesn't work when the table is wider than the body block.

[Here's the table.](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=TABLE&q=select%20col0,%20col1,%20col2,%20col3,%20col4,%20col5,%20col6,%20col7,%20col8,%20col9,%20col10,%20col11,%20col12,%20col13%20from%201QHiNEBR2BojyGCnNuE5mBCu5oWJyeBtgsw1A_iw&containerId=gviz_canvas)

You'll note I'm having trouble with column width too, as I can't get that last column to stretch out.

Also, my backup plan is to allow users to simply download the table, but I can't figure out how to set the link to download the table.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Embedded tables use the Google Charts table visualization, which supports a fixed header if you set the height. See the  [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options) for details.